# How to change the unit of the Y axis in the IO Graph in Wireshark 2.x?

Tags: wireshark, bandwidth

In Wireshark 1.x this option is available in the GUI, but in Wireshark 2.x it's not available in the IO Graph window. Where can the unit of the Y axis (i.e.packets/tick, bytes/tick etc.) be set in Wireshark 2.x?

Answer (score 0):

You double-click the field and a drop-down box appears.